# DatePicker always gives January in returned date

Tags: android, kotlin

I implemented a `DatePicker` in a fragment and when I pick a date from the `Datepicker` dialog it returns the year and the day that I selected but I keep getting January in month.
I printed the value of `monthOfYear` to see if it is changing and it gives the correct `Int` for the month selected but when I set a static month like this `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5)` it gives same problem which means I guess something is wrong with setting the `monthOfYear` in cal?
Anything I'm doing wrong?

```kotlin
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
val dateSetListener =  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfMonth)

        val format = "dd.MM.yyyy"
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(format,Locale.US)
        binding.test.text = sdf.format(cal.time)
        viewModel.updateDate(cal.timeInMillis)
}

binding.date.setOnClickListener {
    DatePickerDialog(
        requireContext(),
        R.style.ThemeOverlay_App_DatePicker,
        dateSetListener,
        cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    ).show()
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Do not use `java.util.Calendar` anymore if you don't have to. Use classes from`java.time` instead, such as `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` for example.

Comment: Are you sure the line `cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfMonth)` does not mess up the date values? It might get set after the month, so any value less than 32 might reset the month to 0 (JAN). But that's just a guess, could be some kind of type here in the question as well.

Comment: Yeah exactly i think i didn't see the auto suggestion i just clicked enter instead of DAY_OF_YEAR i should use DAY_OF_MONTH anyway thank you for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the day of **month** as the DAY_OF_**YEAR**, so it is overriding the month you set. But I agree with the above comment. Use LocalDate instead of Calendar.

Calendar, Date, TimeZone, and other `java.util` date-time related classes are considered obsolete. Unfortunately, DatePicker predates availability of the `java.time` classes like LocalDate, so it may be easiest to use Calendar if you're just converting to UTC millis and back.

Comment: Consider `java.time` instead, @Aydev

Comment: Haha sorry my head is full I need to clear some cache, java.time it is.